# (VB6) Slicing a string before a certain point

Tags: vb6, substring, slice

Suppose I have a variable set to the path of an image.

```
Let img = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Test\Stuff\Icons\test.jpg"
```

I want to slice everything before `"\Icons"` using Vb6. So after slicing the string it would be `"\Icons\test.jpg"` only.

I have tried fiddling with the `Mid$` function in VB6, but I haven't really had much success. I am aware of the fact that Substring isn't a function available in vb6, but in vb.net only.

Comment: use `Instr` to find the location you want then `Mid`, `Left` or `Right` to get the desired sub string portion

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks! I figured out how to do it with that. I set the value of the Instr function (which returned the starting position of the string) to a variable, used that variable in the Mid$ function to get all the text starting from the string I wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first \icons

```
path = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Test\Stuff\Icons\test.jpg"

?mid$(path, instr(1, path, "\icons\", vbTextCompare))

>  \Icons\test.jpg
```

Or after the last should there be > 1

```
path = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\Test\Icons\Stuff\Icons\test.jpg"

?right$(path, len(path) - InStrRev(path, "\icons\", -1, vbTextCompare) + 1)

>  \Icons\test.jpg
```

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty easy to do generically using the `Split` function. I wrote a method to demonstrate it's use and for grins it takes an optional parameter to specify how many directories you want returned. Passing no number returns a file name, passing a very high number returns a full path (either local or UNC). Please note there is no error handling in the method.

```
Private Function GetFileAndBasePath(ByVal vPath As String, Optional ByVal baseFolderLevel = 0) As String
    Dim strPathParts() As String
    Dim strReturn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strPathParts = Split(vPath, "\")
    Do While i <= baseFolderLevel And i <= UBound(strPathParts)
        If i > 0 Then
            strReturn = strPathParts(UBound(strPathParts) - i) & "\" & strReturn
        Else
            strReturn = strPathParts(UBound(strPathParts))
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    GetFileAndBasePath = strReturn

End Function
```